# Remove default display style attribute for html button in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know how to remove a default display style attribute for a input button in JavaScript function. Tried removeAtrribute but no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

HTML
`<input id="myInput" type="text" value="Hello world" style="display:none">`

JavaScript
`document.getElementById('myInput').style.display = "";`

As a function

```
function resetDisplay(element) {
   element.style.display = "";
}
```

And call that function like this
`resetDisplay(document.getElementById('myInput'))`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4s523x2/)

Comment: I did try and it didn't work. I have two buttons - button1 and button2 in which button2 only has style="display:none;" to initially hide it. When I click Button1 it should do something and hide button1 and unhide button2 and vice versa. So in my case it did switch from button1 to button2 when clicked but button2 immediately goes away and doesn't stay and displays finally button1 only. Did try as suggested above to remove default style for both buttons in JavaScript function and reassigned block and none styles accordingly when button clicked but no luck. Please suggest and thanks.

Comment: @23456 If this is your problem it seems that your question is incomplete. I provided an answer to the problem you described in the question. Perhaps you should rephrase the question. :-)